# How to make datatables editable in Shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have managed to build a shiny app that reads csv files in datatables but my problem is now making the output editable. I tried to use jquery.jeditable.js but it is not working. Below is the full code I built. I would be grateful if anyone can help. Thanks!

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(""),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file", "Upload the file", 
            accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
  helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
  tags$hr(style="padding:0px;margin:0px")
  ),

mainPanel(
tags$div(id = "main", dataTableOutput("dtt"), 
           style = "font-size:85%; position: absolute; left: 150px; width: 
1150px; top: 140px")),


tags$script(" $('#main').editable(function(value, settings) {
   console.log(this);
            console.log(value);
            console.log(settings);
            return(value);
}, {
            type    : 'text',
            indicator : 'Saving...',
            tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
});") 


tags$head(tags$script(src="jquery.jeditable.js"))

)              
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

data <- reactive({
file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()}
df <- read.csv(file = file1$datapath, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
})


output$dtt <-renderDataTable(data(),
              extensions = 'Buttons',                    
              selection = "multiple",
              options = list(pageLength = 25, scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = 
'500px', 
                             dom = 'lBfrtip', buttons = 
                               list(list(
                                 extend = 'collection',
                                 buttons = c('csv', 'pdf'),
                                 text = 'Download'
                               ))
              ))

 })
```

Comment: take a look at the `rhandsontable` package. You can easily edit a table.

Comment: Thanks! But do you have any leads on how to apply css to rhandsontable? Like applying a dataTable plugin?

Comment: in your post, you don't mention CSS, you want an editable table. This might help:https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28#issuecomment-236293247

Comment: Super! It works. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was update my DT r package in rstudios and that came along with the editing feature.